# What happens if the first letter of a method in a java program is a capital / upper case letter?

Tags: java, methods

I am aware that in Java language, the first letter of a method should desirably be lower case, but what happens if it becomes a capital letter?

I tried changing the first letter of the methods in my program to capital letters, but it made no difference.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Replace3meth
{
    String str, newstr;
    int len, vcount;
    public void Accept()
    { // obtaining input
        System.out.println("\f");//clearing the screen
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        str = sc.nextLine();
        str = str.toLowerCase();
    } // accept() method ends
    public void ReplaceVowel()
    {
        len = str.length();
        newstr = "";
        vcount = 0;
        char c;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        { // finding no. of vowels
            c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
            {
                c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
                vcount++;
            } // if function ends
            newstr = newstr + c;
        } // for loop ends
    } // replaceVowel() method ends
    public void Display()
    { // printing output
        System.out.println("Original sentence:" +str);
        System.out.println("New sentence: "+newstr);
        System.out.println("No. of vowels: "+vcount);
    } // display() method ends
    public static void Main()
    { // calling all methods
        Replace3meth obj = new Replace3meth();
        obj.Accept();
        obj.ReplaceVowel();
        obj.Display();
    } // main() method ends
} // class ends
```

This is a simple program to convert all the vowels in a sentence to upper case. Even after changing all the method names to start with a capital letter, the program worked properly.

PS: I use BlueJ (not VSCode), so I can used main() instead of main(String[] args)

Comment: then people reviewing your code, or maintaining your code might start calling you names. Yes, it'll work, but that means it's a good thing to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method names don't **have** to start with a lower case letter. It's just a [shared convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) so all developers are on the same page and people reading your code don't have to add extra cognitive load to quickly parse it.

Method names are case-sensitive, though. So if, for any reason, a name is expected to have a certain case it has to be respected.

One example is methods that need to be implemented because they are declared in an interface or abstract class (if the method you have to implement is called `doStuff` you can't implement it as `DoStuff` or `dostuff`).

Another example is the `main` method, which is [the method the JVM expects to call when you run a class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4). It has to maintain the same case (and the fact that it has to be public, static, void and have an array of strings as its only argument), so you can't call it `Main` or `MaiN`. But that is a requirement of the JVM, not of the language.

Comment: With the exception of `main(String[] args)`, which does have to start with a lowercase letter, if you want it to work as an entry point.

Comment: @Michael unless you mean as an entrypoint, even if it's called Main it can be called

Comment: So when can it NOT be called Main()? I don't understand what entry point refers to?

Comment: @MrGubbo I added some clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens, the code will still compile. You can name your methods `getName`, `GETname`, `getNAME`, `GETNAME`, or `GeTnAmE` and the compiler will not care.

Who will care however are human people reading and trying to understand the code. Make it easy for your fellow programmers and future you to read code.

You could also name them `föΘBÄRẞ` and your code will still compile. But nobody reading the code could make any sense of it.

Comment: @Michael thanks, ∀ is in fact invalid. Replaced it with Ä to make it a valid identifier :)

Comment: I did always find it funny what chars are considered "valid". There are plenty of non-printable characters which are valid, but "∀" is somehow bad. Kind of arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Usually nothing special happens to the code itself, but other people used to the conventional style will have troubles understanding it and therefore you will e.g. have a lower rate of answers to your SO-questions if they contain code that doesn't follow the conventions.

But because you mentioned it extra:

To start a java program with the `java` command (this is the standard way), your main method has to have a defined signature, as stated in the documentation [The java Command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#description):

> The method declaration has the following form:
>
> `public static void main(String[] args)`

So in this case, if your main method is named `Main` and doesn't have that exact give signature (public static, no return value, array of String as parameter), your program will not start.

And of course if you are overloading or overwriting or implementing methods from other classes or interfaces, you have to copy their name exactly and must not change the case - and as e.g. overwriting of `equals` and `hashcode` from the `Object` class are quit common, it would result in a mixture of casing, and from my experience I can say this is super confusing - even if you want to understand your own code a few days after you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax wise it wont make any difference but the standard says that you should be following camel case when naming methods or variables.
An Excerpt from official doc.

**"Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized."**

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html